# CSS media query rule not being applied

Tags: css, media-queries

At line 449 of [this page](https://www.thedesignersroom.com.au/our-work/), there is:

```
@media (min-width: 981px) {
    #tdr-gallery-our-work .wpb_image_grid .wpb_image_grid_ul .isotope-item {
        max-width: 9.09090909% !important;
        position: relative !important;
        left: auto !important;
        top: auto !important;
    }
}
```

However, if I inspect the LI element of the image gallery in the middle of the page, code inspector says that only the following rule is being applied:

```
.wpb_image_grid .wpb_image_grid_ul .isotope-item {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 1px 1px 0;
    max-width: 8.92857142%;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    position: relative !important;
    left: auto !important;
    top: auto !important;
}
```

The `div#tdr-gallery-our-work` definitely contains this image gallery, but it's not even being detected by the code inspector. It's in the source code, so why isn't it being applied?

I am in a browser on a `1680px` monitor, and the media query takes place at `(min-width: 981px)`.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that your rules are not being overwritten by other !important rules elsewhere in the stylesheet? Also, can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Your rule is well applied on my side

Comment: Same I see it applied in the Chrome inspector

Comment: Damn. This site does not play well with my Chrome. I do a hard refresh, and the problem remains. If I load the page in Firefox, I see the rule being applied too.